# Which provider do I use to bind my database repositories in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I am working with laravel 5 and I am novice developer so I just learnt how to use the Repository pattern. Now as novices go, I first use the routes.php file to bind my `UserRepositoryInterface` to `DbUserRepository` like so:

```
App::bind('UserRepositoryInterface', 'DbUserRepository');
```

This is just psuedo, image the namepspaces with the above code too.

So after this I realized that that there is something called a Service Provider which is supposed to contain code like so. Now I refactored this in the `AppServiceProvider` in my `Providers` folder and it works fine still.

But since I will be having so many more repositories, is this is a good idea to place them into the `AppServiceProvider` or should I go ahead and make a dedicated provider for my repositories and bind them there? What is the best way to do this? Is there a standard for this?

Comment: I think this is going to be down to personal preference and the scale of your application. I do it the way that you described and split my `AppServiceProvider` up in to logical methods. So I put all these types bindings in to a `registerInterfaces()` method and then call it from the `register` method in my `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: I just went ahead and created a `RepositoryServiceProvider`. And I guess you are right, this is some thing that would boil down to my personal preferences rather than a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So later I got to understand that this all about preference so I coded a `RepositoryServiceProvider` in which I bind all the repository contracts to the desired implementations like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Archive\Repositories\TenantRepository;
use Archive\Repositories\TenantRepositoryEloquent;

use Archive\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Archive\Repositories\UserRepositoryEloquent;

use Archive\Repositories\OrderRepository;
use Archive\Repositories\OrderRepositoryEloquent;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(TenantRepository::class, TenantRepositoryEloquent::class);
        $this->app->bind(UserRepository::class, UserRepositoryEloquent::class);
        $this->app->bind(OrderRepository::class, OrderRepositoryEloquent::class);
    }
}
```